# I need some support for gcovr and cobertura

Tags: python, jenkins, cobertura, gcov, gcovr

I am trying to create a pdf file which shows coverage of my unit tests. And same I need to push to Jenkins.
Steps:

- I clone the repo.
- Make the Env and Build it locally.
- Run Batchfile for unit tests.

AND
When I run gcov in my local PC, I get coverage for all the .c files as expected and I get a complete **cobertura.xml** which I use to generate pdf.

Here is the problem:

The same files are commited and pushed to jenkins build, But I see missing report for a single .c file.

Tried to debug the gcovr.py file, here I use

```
         (out,err) = subprocess.Popen( cmd, env=env, 
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE ).communicate()
```

Then, When I print **"out"** I don't see `a.c.gov` file creating, which I see for other files.

When tried to analyze I found in Jenkins generated **"coubertura.xml"** the package wasn't present, I think it is beacause .gcov file wasn't created.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are many details missing here. What gcovr versions are you using? Does Jenkins run  on a Windows system? What kind of directory layout does your project use, and where in this layout are your tests and the a.c file?

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad,

I tried shortening the name of the test.c file in Jenkins and also change names in Makefile
, I got the required coverage.